# Why do we use specific probability distributions in certain contexts?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

For instance, in survival analysis and modelling time to failure, one is likely to use a weibull distribution or exponential distribution. I'm struggling to understand the intuition behind this. What makes these distributions more suited to the context than, say, a chi-square distribution or a beta distribution or a log-normal distribution?

Comment: It is based on assumptions about the model. For time to failure, the assumption is that components will fail independently of one another and that the failure rate at any time is constant (the normal operating assumptions range of time). From that, the exponential distribution of failure time arises.

Comment: It depends on your model. Both a Weibull distribution and an exponential distribution are examples of generalised gamma distributions, with simple explanations of the parameters (for a Weibull distribution, a failure rate which is proportional to a power of time, and for an exponential distribution a constant failure rate).  So too is a chi-square distribution (probably better expressed as a gamma distribution) and if your model is that you get a major failure after a fixed number of minor failures with a constant minor failure rate then you might want to use that in particular circumstances.